# Unable to access config.handlebars in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, config, handlebars.js, ember-rails

I've got an existing rails app, and I've added an ember front-end. I'm having trouble deploying the new version (which includes Ember for the first time) to Heroku.

The problem is that I'm unable to run rake tasks in production mode.

I discovered this when I tried to rake db:migrate on heroku. I got the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `handlebars' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000004f0de90>/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
/app/config/application.rb:60:in `<class:Application>'
```

I get the same error if I try to run any tasks locally in production mode, e.g.:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake -T
```

the offending line, from config/application.rb:

```
config.handlebars.templates_root = 'ember/templates'
```

for various reasons, I had to move the ember templates down one file level. and it needs to stay there. everything works fine in development mode.

Any idea how I can fix this?

tried upgrading the ember-rails gem. this didn't help. (I'm using 0.12.0)

Comment: Did this work locally? You might want to add that to the question

Comment: it's working in development mode. but when try to run rake tasks in production mode, locally or on heroku, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trick was to move ember-rails gem out of assets group